# iOS13 Crash -[UIWindowScene _enumerateWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:asCopy:stopped:withBlock:]?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios13

Since iOS 13.0 was released, I've been seeing a lot of occurrencies of this crash in our app:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1846cf278 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1843f80a4 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x184998480 -[NSConcretePointerArray dealloc]
3  UIKitCore                      0x1888da3b8 -[UIWindowScene _enumerateWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:asCopy:stopped:withBlock:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1888d9f74 -[UIWindowScene _topVisibleWindowPassingTest:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1886fc4c4 +[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1886fc854 -[UIWindow _targetWindowForPathIndex:atPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x18873c080 ____updateTouchesWithDigitizerEventAndDetermineIfShouldSend_block_invoke.52
8  UIKitCore                      0x18874b738 _UIEventHIDEnumerateChildren
9  UIKitCore                      0x18873f8d0 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
10 UIKitCore                      0x188742dc4 __handleEventQueueInternal
11 UIKitCore                      0x18873bc38 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18464d090 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18464cfe8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18464c780 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1846478cc __CFRunLoopRun
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18464716c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17 GraphicsServices               0x18e47f328 GSEventRunModal
18 UIKitCore                      0x1886b1d0c UIApplicationMain
19 MyApp                           0x100d3ba64 main + 18 (main.swift:18)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1844d2424 start
```

It only happens in iOS **13.0.0 (17A577)**

We don't have much context on what steps are causing this, all we have at the moment is that stack trace.

Is anybody else experiencing something similar?

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I got lots of crash that same as above

Comment: Nothing! I can only imagine this is a UIKit issue with iOS 13.

Comment: I've just discovered that this is associated with a Clevertap campaign. I still don't know what causes it though. But disabling the campaign got rid of the crash!

Comment: I have the same issue with iOS 13.1.x. And my app also has CleverTap integrated, so what Lio said makes sense.

Comment: FYI Clevertap has solved this issue in 3.7.0, Segment-Clevertap released a fix with that version too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have `strong` reference to UIWindow which you created
2. Use `makeKeyAndVisible` instead of setting `window.hidden = false`